# php to find youtube embed code

Tags: php

I am writing a script that takes the url of a video on youtube and from that will get the video embed code for that video. I am using

```
file_get_contents();
```

to get the page. Once I've got the contents of the page does anyone know how I can extract the embed code?

Thanks

Geoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions via [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), you'll just have to write the right pattern.

Or, if that suits you, you can even use [gdata api for youtube](http://code.google.com/intl/sl-SI/apis/youtube/overview.html) or [Zend Gdata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html). Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since YouTube provides an [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) service, which offers what you are looking for, I would **strongly** recommend that you use it instead of attempting manual parsing of the page.

The API to their oEmbed service is explained in this [YouTube API Blog Post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think i can get the embed code just by getting the file contents because its added into the page dynamically if you click the embed code button. Have to figure out the API